# How to export to swf without quality loss?

Tags: animation, flash

I created an animation in flash CS5 and when I export it to swf I have serious quality loss. Do you know how to resolve it? How to optimize quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more details would be helpful, but here's my best guess. The animation was built natively in Flash, and you're publishing it as a .swf, right? That shouldn't cause any quality loss in and of itself, but SWF players have a 'quality' setting that you may have set low. How to check and change this setting depends on what player you're using.